# Correct arrangement of this sentence

Tags: grammar

I currently have this sentence:

*James Albert Bonsack took on the challenge and created a machine in 1880; despite losing his first prototype to a fire.*

But I am not sure about how it is best to arrange it. Alternative:

*James Albert Bonsack took on the challenge and despite losing his first prototype to a fire; created a machine in 1880.*

Comment: Stop using this bloody horizontal scroll.

Comment: I removed it. ...

Comment: Apologizes, Its common in the programming section :) So thought it may apply here.

Comment: Hmmm ... is "first prototype" tautologous? Would not any -type subsequent to the prototype, even one which recreated the original in every respect, be at least a *deuterotype*?

Comment: @StoneyB Sorry. I have no idea what you are saying :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the site! Both options are perfectly fine. Perhaps putting the *despite...* phrase earlier in the sentence gives it slightly more emphasis.

Your punctuation is off, however. If you choose to separate the *despite...* phrase from the rest of the sentence, it needs to be surrounded with commas. If it comes at the end, only a comma before it is necessary (since you already have a full stop after it).

> James Albert Bonsack took on the challenge and created a machine in 1880, despite losing his first prototype to a fire.
>
> James Albert Bonsack took on the challenge and, despite losing his first prototype to a fire, created a machine in 1880.

Or you could dispense with the commas altogether.

Comment: @user2469515: Oh haha, that's funny, didn't know that was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Both work but learn your **semicolons**. They were wrong here, totally **cutting the flow**. Fixed:

*James Albert Bonsack took on the challenge and created a machine in 1880, despite losing his first prototype to a fire.*

*James Albert Bonsack took on the challenge and, despite losing his first prototype to a fire, created a machine in 1880.*

Something else is the 2nd comma needed in the 2nd, so "despite losing his first prototype to a fire" is surrounded by commas to be a non-restrictive clause.